# Updating javascript variable after .NET partial postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

In my game's vb.net, I'm creating a button dynamically like this:

```
Dim nextButton As New ImageButton

With nextButton 
    .ID = "nextButton" & directionID.ToString
    AddHandler .Click, AddressOf directionPath_Click
End With
```

In the game when the button is clicked, it fires, and updates a variable called directionPath.

That part works fine when I run through the Visual Studio debugger.

Howver I need to update a variable clientside in javascript using the value of directionPath.

Whenever I click the button, the javascript part is not getting the updated value.

I read up on partial postbacks and tried a bunch of things, but nothing is working.

Is this even possible?

thanks!

Comment: You are trying to change the server side handler via javascript? How about instead push whatever criteria the javascript would use to change that up with the post and branch there in the server code. Sounds a million times easier to me.

Comment: @asawyer no I just need to get the server variable when it is being updated with the onclick event is fired. thanks

Comment: You could try registering a startup script in `directionPath_Click` that sets the variable.  I think the syntax is something like `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "MyScriptKey", "myjsvar = '" & myservervar.ToString() & "';", True)`.  The 4th parameter is the JavaScript to be run after the postback.

Comment: @Mark can you please expand on that in an answer so that the formatting is easier to read? I think it may work...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side code can register JavaScript code that will run on the client after a postback using the [`ScriptManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  There are a number of `RegisterXXX` methods available, and I've never been entirely sure of which one to use in which situation, but I have used [`RegisterStartupScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx) successfully (although even that is confusing about whether to pass in the page or some control - e.g. the `UpdatePanel` as the first parameter).

So, you may need to experiment a little, but try something like this in your `directionPath_Click` method:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    Me, ' The page
    Me.GetType(), ' The type for the page class
    "MyScriptKey", ' A unique identifier for the script
    "myjsvar = '" & myservervar.ToString() & "';", ' The JavaScript to run
    True ' Add <script> tags around the code
)
```